# Spark Jdbc connection JDBCOptions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use the method savetable in the Spark JdbcUtils

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala

The defination of the method is the following. It accepts the JDBCOptions as one of the parameter.

```
def saveTable(
      df: DataFrame,
      tableSchema: Option[StructType],
      isCaseSensitive: Boolean,
      options: JDBCOptions)
```

Following is the class of the JDBCOptions

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCOptions.scala

While i am initializing the JDBCOptions with the url,transaction isolation level etc  it is throwing errors.

Can you provide insights in  initialization of the JDBCOptions

```
 val options :JDBCOptions = Map("url" -> "JDBCUrl")
Error Type Map doesnt conform to be JDBCOption Type
```

How to initialize with correct type ?

Comment: Providing the error message would help.

Comment: @AydinK. I am not sure how to initialize it ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html

Comment: Or here (chapter „Running Jdbc to other Databases“): https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases

Comment: @AydinK. I looked into them. They are using using Options but i am using the JDBCOptions. Both are different.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165860/discussion-between-achyuth-and-aydin-k).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the Map in a `new JDBCOptions(...)` call

```
// url and dbtable are required
val options:JDBCOptions = new JDBCOptions(Map("url" -> "JDBCUrl", "dbtable" -> "foo"))
```